# GCC me genera archivo assembly vacío

Tags: c, ensamblador, gcc

¡Hola! Estoy tratando de optimizar un programa en C, con distintas optimizaciones. Ahora tengo que intentar que GCC pueda autovectorizar. A medida que voy trabajando en el programa genero el archivo assembly con la opción "-S" de GCC, pero al activar los niveles de optimización superiores al nivel 0 el archivo assembly no contiene prácticamente nada. Uso gcc-7, y probando con versiones más viejas del compilador me hace lo mismo.

Primero el código en C:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HEIGHT 2000
#define WIDTH 1000

static unsigned int idx(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int stride){
  return y * stride + x;
}

static void integral_image(const unsigned char * restrict in, unsigned int * restrict out){
  unsigned int row_sum = 0;
  unsigned char *newin = __builtin_assume_aligned(in, 16);
  unsigned char *newout = __builtin_assume_aligned(out, 16);

  for(unsigned int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x){
    row_sum += newin[x];
    newout[x] = row_sum;
  }

  for(unsigned int y = 1; y < HEIGHT; ++y){
    row_sum = 0;

    for(unsigned w = 0; w < WIDTH; w += 4){
      const unsigned int i1 = idx(w, y, WIDTH);
      const unsigned int old1 = idx(w, y - 1, WIDTH);
      const unsigned int i2 = idx(w + 1, y, WIDTH);
      const unsigned int old2 = idx(w, y - 1, WIDTH);
      const unsigned int i3 = idx(w + 2, y, WIDTH);
      const unsigned int old3 = idx(w + 2, y - 1, WIDTH);
      const unsigned int i4 = idx(w + 3, y, WIDTH);
      const unsigned int old4 = idx(w + 3, y - 1, WIDTH);

      row_sum += newin[i1];
      newout[i1] = row_sum + newout[old1];

      row_sum += newin[i2];
      newout[i2] = row_sum + newout[old2];

      row_sum += newin[i3];
      newout[i3] = row_sum + newout[old3];

      row_sum += newin[i4];
      newout[i4] = row_sum + newout[old4];
    }
  }
}
```

Y ahora lo que me genera GCC al compilar con -S:

```
.file   "thrash.c"
.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.1.0-10ubuntu1~16.04.york0) 7.1.0"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta de que son `static` ... es decir, no se pueden llamar desde fuera del módulo. Si el módulo no exporta ninguna función pública, el compilador no las genera. Quita el `static`, o añade alguna función que las use.

Comment: ¡ Valla *metedura de pata* por mi parte ! Ya me parecía raro ...

Comment: Muchas gracias, otra vez. Solo por curiosidad, si tenés idea y no es algo que ocupe mucho de tu tiempo, ¿Por qué al llamar a la función desde el main el problema no se soluciona? (El código producido solo se encarga de poner el valor de retorno de main en el registro indicado). Como digo, no quiero hacerte perder el tiempo, lo importante ya lo solucionaste.

Comment: No estoy seguro de entenderte bien. Si desde el `main` llamas a una función no `static` de ese archivo problemático, en el `main.s` debe aparecer el código de la llamada, y en el otro (el que muestras) **si debería** de aparecer el cuerpo.

Comment: Precisamente me refiero a hacer una llamada desde main a una función static.

Comment: Eso solo se puede hacer si está todo en el mismo archivo; pero es imposible que te genere un `.s` vacío así; el código de `main( )` tiene que estar, por mucha generación `inline` que se realice. Garantizado.

Comment: Así es, muchas gracias.